# React, on every render i get previous value of a variable

Tags: reactjs

```
    const playerInputHandler = React.useCallback((value) => {
        setPlayer1(value)
        setPlayer2(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1)


        setTimeout(() => {
            winConditionCheck(player1, player2)
        }, 1000)
    }, [winConditionCheck, player1, player2])
```

in winConditionCheck callback `player1` and `player2` values are the values of previous render.

How can i get the current value of `player1` and `player2` as soon as i set values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect someone to be able to help you when you don't provide how `setPlayer1` and `setPlayer2` are defined and what the observable behavior you expect is.

Comment: it is useState's set function

Comment: You need to post more code that may be affecting / affected by the result of your setTimeout(and winConditionCheck,. player1, player2 because you apparently need them as deps)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

**You could solve it using refs:**

```js
    const player1Ref = useRef(0);
    const player2Ref = useRef(0);

    const playerInputHandler = useCallback((value) => {
        player1Ref.current = value;
        player2Ref.current = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

        setTimeout(() => {
            winConditionCheck()
        }, 1000)
    }, [winConditionCheck, player1Ref, player2Ref])
```

As seen on [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14010) github issue, React handles state variables in an immutable manner, meaning that each time it is changed a new object is used.
When calling setTimeout you are passing a reference to an object that will not be connected to the component state.

If you **insist** on using states you could bind them like this:

```js
    const player1Ref = useRef(0);
    const player2Ref = useRef(0);

    const [player1, setPlayer1] = useState(0);
    const [player2, setPlayer2] = useState(0);
    
    const playerInputHandler = useCallback((value) => {
        setPlayer1(value)
        setPlayer2(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1)

        setTimeout(() => {
            winConditionCheck()
        }, 1000)
    }, [winConditionCheck, player1Ref, player2Ref, player1, player2])

    useEffect(() => {
      player1Ref.current = player1;
    }, [player1Ref, player1]);

    useEffect(() => {
      player2Ref.current = player2;
    }, [player2Ref, player2]);
```

Make sure to use the `player1Ref` and `player2Ref` in your winConditionCheck implementation and dependency arrays.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is definitively correct when you're speculating on how the rest of the original code was written and there was no information provided on how it was to be used.

Comment: Because it's a closure issue related to javascript, it doesn't matter how winCondition is implemented if the underlying object is state and is passed as an argument.  

It can be directly inferred that the player objects are numbers, and based on the way OP asked the question it's implemented using a state.

Comment: But you're guessing on all of that.

Comment: No, OP clearly replied to your comment that he implemented it with useState.  And if you would have taken the time to recreate the problem and do some research on closures in javascript you would have come to the same conclusion (I have past experience with this exact problem).  
So I would appreciate for you to take 1 minute to actually read my answer and try to understand how it is based on direct information provided in this thread instead of passive aggressively replying to my answer because of my "New Contributor" badge